# Connecting to Azure DB from SQL management studio is failing MSSQLSERVER_10060

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm trying to connect to the sql server that has been created on Azure using SQL management studio, but i'm getting the following error.

[image]

```
Error message: An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10060)
```

I have enabled the client IP in the SQL server firewall settings.

Please let me know if anything else need to be taken cared. Thank you

Comment: This type of error will come when there is some typo in your server name. Typical Azure SQL Server name would be like `xxx.database.windows.net`. Please make sure you have this correct server name is in your SSMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this error, try one of the following actions:

- Make sure that you have configured the firewall on the computer to allow this instance of SQL Server to accept connections. That is, If you are trying to connect from within a corporate network, outbound traffic over port 1433 may not be allowed by your network's firewall. If so, you cannot connect to your Azure SQL Database server unless your IT department opens port 1433. On the Azure Side, you also need to check if the NSG (associated with that subnet the Azure SQL server sitting in) allows the client IP with the specific port 1433.
- Add the client IP in the SQL server firewall settings if you enable a server-level firewall.
- Telnet the current IP of your Azure SQL Database server with the port to verify the network connection.

Comment: I facing this exact same issure am trying to access the azure SQL Server through SSMS on my local machine. Just like the OP, I was able to access the server initially, but then after a gap of a day, I am not able to access it.  I have disabled the Windows Firewall on my local machine and also added my client IP address to server firewall, however I am still not able to access it. Please advice on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure the server name you are connecting to is correct.
- Check that your own firewall allows your connection across the internet to the instance.

Typically if it was the Azure firewall side, it would prompt you to add your IP to the firewall rules, provided you're connecting with an admin account.

Answer (score 0):

This cause by network restriction in your lan. you can try by switching your network connnection. It worked for me.